# MS Access - Link Master / Child fields not working when linking subreport to master report

Tags: ms-access

I have a subreport not connecting effectively to the main report.  I created the parent report, then I dragged and dropped a query into the detail portion of the report.  When I link on the appropriate field, it seems to be ignoring it, and is bringing back every block of records from the child portion, and tying it to the master record.

When I filter the master query to just one record, it works as expected because it only has one combination to deal with.  When I filter it to two records, it starts multiplying things, just as it would in a cartesian product

A query that links these two original queries, in the way that I think the forms should do it, works appropriately.

This is the query that links master and child queries from the form:

```
SELECT [WT1 for Complete WT Container].Number, 
[WT1 for Complete WT Container].ItemID, 
[WT1 for Complete WT Container].ItemRecordNumber, 
[WT3 Detail and Transpose].ItemRecordNumber, 
[WT3 Detail and Transpose].Itm, 
[WT3 Detail and Transpose].ItemDescription, 
Count([WT1 for Complete WT Container].Number) AS CountOfNumber

FROM 
[WT1 for Complete WT Container] INNER JOIN [WT3 Detail and Transpose] 
ON [WT1 for Complete WT Container].ItemRecordNumber = [WT3 Detail and Transpose].ItemRecordNumber
GROUP BY [WT1 for Complete WT Container].Number, 
[WT1 for Complete WT Container].ItemID, 
[WT1 for Complete WT Container].ItemRecordNumber, 
[WT3 Detail and Transpose].ItemRecordNumber, 
[WT3 Detail and Transpose].Itm, 
[WT3 Detail and Transpose].ItemDescription;
```

What am I missinng?  I'm filling in the Link Master Fields / Link Child Fields with ItemRecordNumber.  That should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, having the fields from the main report in the header section, and the subreport data in the detail section does not work right.  both have to be in the detail section of the main report for this to work.  After I moved the fields in the main part, it worked.